# Identifying groups with same column value and count them

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am working with a dataframe, consisting of a continuity column df['continuity'] and a column group df['group'].
Both are binary columns.

I want to add an extra column 'group_id' that gives consecutive rows of 1s the same integer value, where the first group of rows have a
1, then 2 etc. After each time where the continuity value of a row is 0, the counting should start again at 1.

Since this question is rather specific, I'm not sure how to tackle this vectorized. Below an example, where the first two
columns are the input and the column the output I'd like to have.

```
continuity  group   group_id
1           0       0
1           1       1
1           1       1
1           1       1
1           0       0
1           1       2
1           1       2
1           1       2
1           0       0
1           0       0
1           1       3
1           1       3
0           1       1
0           0       0
1           1       1
1           1       1
1           0       0
1           0       0
1           1       2
1           1       2
```

Comment: Can there be consecutive 0's?

Comment: Yes, they happen a lot. I'll edit my example.

Comment: What if both are 0? continuity and group

Comment: Then group_id should be 0

Comment: Really, I goes away and build an answer, I come back you have changed the data? Ugh.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited based on Tai's questions. But the data didn't change drastically did it?

Comment: It changed enough my rather optimized answer does not work...  When vectorizing, the specific sequence often matters.

Comment: @BramZijlstra Please have a well-defined question next time as it will really help us and as Stephen said, it will enable us to do some optimization or simply less work to come up with the results you need.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I thought my example was clear, but I hadn't thought of some of your exceptions. I will add these in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use:

```
#get unique groups in both columns
b = df[['continuity','group']].ne(df[['continuity','group']].shift()).cumsum()
#identify first 1
c = ~b.duplicated() & (df['group'] == 1)
#cumulative sum of first values only if group are 1, else 0 per groups
df['new'] = np.where(df['group'] == 1,
                     c.groupby(b['continuity']).cumsum(), 
                     0).astype(int)
print (df)
    continuity  group  group_id  new
0            1      0         0    0
1            1      1         1    1
2            1      1         1    1
3            1      1         1    1
4            1      0         0    0
5            1      1         2    2
6            1      1         2    2
7            1      1         2    2
8            1      0         0    0
9            1      0         0    0
10           1      1         3    3
11           1      1         3    3
12           0      1         1    1
13           0      0         0    0
14           1      1         1    1
15           1      1         1    1
16           1      0         0    0
17           1      0         0    0
18           1      1         2    2
19           1      1         2    2
```

Comment: `duplicated` is what I would have needed to add to my answer to get it to work after the data changed...  Thanks.